# Power Bi reports Embedding

Tags: security, azure-active-directory, report, powerbi-embedded, multiple-users

how can we control access to the reports and dashboards by setting up authentication and authorization through Azure Active Directory (AD) and Azure AD B2B? can you please explain me in detail that how to embed power bi reports through azure for multiple domain mail id customers?

I am getting the answers in different web pages in different ways but not clearly understood. I am expecting step wise with images screenshots actually if possible.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-sample-for-customers?tabs=net-core

Answer (score 0):

You can authenticate your Azure AD users to access Power BI reports like the below:-

Adding all the users with different domains, guests, and members in a security group or using individual users and giving that security group or individual users access to your Powe BI content like below:-

Created one security group and added users and one service principal in the Azure Ad group like below, You can add your guest users in this group with different domains too:-

[image]

In your Power BI portal > visit > Settings > Admin Portal > Tenant Settings > Use Data Set across workspaces> Add your Security group or individual users in the tab like below:-

[image]

Now you can share your Power BI reports to Azure AD users in 2 ways:-

Sharing the report directly like below:-

[image]

Giving the users or security group access to Power BI dataset on with different permissions refer below:-

Go to workspaces > dataset > … three dots > Manage permissions > Assign users or group with the required permissions like below:-

[image]

You can send the dataset link for users to access or provide direct access to the dataset like below:-

[image]

Direct access with permissions like the below:-

[image]

As you have added the service principal to the security group, Even your Azure AD application can access these reports programmatically.

If your Azure AD is integrated with office 365 you can directly connect your Power BI account to the Office 365 admin center and manage users and groups. Azure AD users and groups can be managed by the office 365 admin center too. Thus, Integrating the office 365 admin center will integrate your Azure AD users and groups with your Power Bi account.

[image]

[Distribute Power BI content to external guest users using Azure Active Directory B2B - Power BI | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/guidance/whitepaper-azure-b2b-power-bi)